# How to run one Http Request between execution time of other two Http Request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, rest-api, api

I am Using Jmeter for load testing so i am little bit struck so here is problem i want run continuously  (Http-request-2) getDriverLocationId in between Trip started(Http request -1) and Trip complete(Http Request -3) with set time interval between Trip started and Trip complete  is possible in Jmeter please tell me with explanation as soon as possible

Real time scenario--> i am working currently on  Uber/ola  like mobile app i have to test load on that application by using set of api  so  let us say Http request-1 consisting of driver location details (lat and long and driver id ) and http request- 1 and Http request -3  consisting of Ride start and  Ride completion details(source lat,long and destination lat,long ) so now i  need to run Http request-2  from trip starting to trip completion Means Http Request 2 runs several time from start trip and complete trip 
[image: Image of above Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, the options are in:

1. Put `getDriverLocationId` request in the separate [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). My expectation is that mobile client application should send location all the time in intervals you can set using [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer).
2. Put `getDriverLocationId` under the [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to run it specified amount of times
3. Put `getDriverLocationId` under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) so the request will be executed unless a specified condition is met (i.e. current location is not equal to destination)

Comment: Hi.... your answer is write and please tell me how to write that condition inside While Controller with small example  because i am new to jmtere

Comment: Hi ... is there possible to add n number of csv file to csv data set config without using ${__threadNum} function in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to:

- request 1 - start
- request 2
- request 2
- ... (number of request 2)
- request 3 - stop

You can you use for instance the [Loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) in which case you can repeat the request for a number of times. Or the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) which allows you to run until the condition in the while is no longer true. For more options look [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers). You would likely also use some timer to wait between every consecutive request.

Your example is missing some, in all likelihood, needed elements. So have a read in the [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/) :-)

(typos corrected)